# How to create xml text and display the text in scene by using script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I needed to create one xml text file and display in this text in scene by (using box) using script? I have created one xml text file i.e located in c Drive. Please see my below code and help to me by using C#. The below code using ngui label. But displaying using box is fine.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

public class Xml : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        XmlDocument xml=new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(Application.dataPath+"/Resources/text.xml");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () { }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        UILabel subtitle = GameObject.Find("Label").GetComponent();
        subtitle.text = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the text from the XML file, can't you just use the [InnerXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.xml.xmldocument.innerxml.aspx) property of your reader? You'll need to move the XmlDocument to be a member variable of the behavior so you can access the text in OnGUI without having to re-load it every frame.

```
subtitle.text = xml.InnerXml;
```

If you want to do something more sophisticaed, look through the methods of [XMLDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) to see how to browse an XmlFile